# R programming: Remove column name

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, header, tidyr

I am trying to get rid of the X1 and X2 names from the following dataframe of size 4 observations and 2 variables. Need some help.

Dataframe df

```
              X1        X2
Animal       Weight    Height
Cat           25         12
Dog           40         24
Rat           0.2        0.3
```

I tried df[-1,] but that eliminated the Animal  Weight Height row instead of the column names X1 and X2.

Comment: So your "real" column names are in row 1? Do you want to set Animal, Weight and Height as column name instead?

Comment: Hello Martin, Yes, you are right.

Comment: Try `colnames(df) <- c("Animal", "Weight", "Height")` and then remove your first row.

Comment: Martin, I tried it but all it did was to now replace X1 and X2 with Weight and Height.

Comment: Do you want "Animals" as variable?

Comment: Animals does not need to be the variable. There should be only 2 variables - Weight and Height.

Comment: Maybe `c("Animal","Cat","Dog","Rat")` are `rownames(df)`? In that case, `df <- df[-1,] ; colnames(df) <- c("Weight","Height")`

Comment: This is my first post on stackoverflow and it looks like I cannot attach the R file or csv.

Comment: Basically, after doing certain operations with a dataframe, I ended up this situation where the column names are X1 and X2. Just need to delete the column row so that the column names will then become Weight and Height.

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused. What should your desired output look like? (Please edit your question). `colnames(df) <- c("Weight", "Height")` should replace X1 and X2.

Comment: Hello Martin and Ian, I realized that after I do what both of you suggested, I do not get to the end state that I want. However, if I do df[-1,] after that, I end up in the correct state. So thanks to both of you.

Comment: Btw, instead of having to explicitly state the column names as Weight and Height, is there a way to simply delete the X1 and X2 headers ?

Comment: You can assign 1st row as column names by `colnames(df) <- df[1, ]` and then remove 1st row `df <- df[-1, ]`

Comment: Ronak, That does not work. It causes the column headings to become c(Animal=4)